# What is the equivalent of PyTorch's BoolTensor in Tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Is there an equivalent of BoolTensor from Pytorch in Tensorflow assuming I have the below usage in Pytorch that I want to migrate to Tensorflow

```
done_mask = torch.BoolTensor(dones.values).to(device)
next_state_values[done_mask] = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `dones`?
Assuming it's a 0/1 tensor, you can convert it to a Bool tensor like this:

```
tf.cast(dones,tf.bool)
```

However, if you want to assign values to a tensor, you can't do it that way.

A way, which I recommend, is to multiply by a matrix of 1/0:

```
next_state_values *= tf.cast(dones!=1,next_state_values.dtype)
```

Another way , that I don't recommend as it gives some issues when using the gradient, is to use tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update. For your case, that would be:

```
indices = tf.where(dones==1)
next_state_values = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(next_state_values ,indices,2*tf.zeros(len(indices)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, dones is a pandas dataframe with dtype bool.
What should be done if it was bool not 0/1 ?

Comment: Then you can do:

`next_state_values *= tf.cast(dones!=True,next_state_values.dtype)`